# R calculates wrong mathematical subtraction when updating dataframe using "sub" function

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

I have a dataframe containing 6 columns: Age, Sex, MoB, YoB, MoI and YoI.
The dataframe contains some patients data, where suffix "B" refers to the patient's Birthday (Month and Year) and suffix "I" refers to the Incidence date of the desease (Month and Year). Since for some rows the Age could be missing, I'd like to calculate Age as difference from **YoI** and **YoB** for those rows without a valid Age value. This is the script I coded so far:

```
# 1. >>> INIT

# 1.1 Initialization
# install.packages("dplyr");
library("dplyr");
message("\nRunning data sanity for fixing missing age\n");

# 1.2 Definition of target files
base_path <- dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile);
dataset_file_in <- paste(base_path, "/", "dataset_missing_age.csv", sep="");
dataset_file_out <- paste(base_path, "/", "dataset_fixed.csv", sep="");

# 1.3 Provide feedback in the consolle
message(paste("Base path                     :", base_path));
message(paste("Target dataset                :", dataset_file_in));
message(paste("Output dataset                :", dataset_file_out));

# 2. >>> READ FILE

# 2.1 Read file from CSV file (assuming semicolon separator)
dataframe_csv <- read.csv(dataset_file_in, sep=";");
message(paste("Dataset rows                  :", nrow(dataframe_csv)));
message(paste("Dataset cols                  :", length(dataframe_csv), "\n"));

# 3. >>> FIX AGE (only where missing)

# 3.1 Add an "helper" column adjusting age with respect of the
# the condition  "Is Incidence date AFTER Birthday date?".
# Example:
# if patient was born in April and got sick in May -> age = YoI - YoB
# if patient was born in April and got sick in March -> age = YoI - YoB - 1
dataframe_csv <- dataframe_csv %>% 
    mutate(IafterB = case_when(
        as.numeric(MoB) >= as.numeric(MoI) ~ 0,
        as.numeric(MoB) < as.numeric(MoI) ~ -1
    ));

# 3.2 Mark with the value "-1" the rows where Age is undefined
dataframe_csv$Age[is.na(dataframe_csv$Age)] <- -1;
    
# 3.3 Define age formula (to improve code readability and maintainability)
calculateAge <- function(YoB, YoI, IafterB) {
  # WE HAVE MANY WEIRD BUGS HERE !!!
  # I'll list some expressions I tried so far, providing an example of the result
  # 1) This calculates: 2006 - 1940 as 68 (instead of 66). Why?
  age_calculated <- YoI - YoB;
  # 2) This works fine, but I don't like the idea to remove 2 years without knowing why
  age_calculated <- YoI - YoB - 2;
  # 3) This calculates: 2006 - 1940 as 68 (instead of 66) as case 1,
  # and also ignores the "IafterB" value. Why?
  age_calculated <- YoI + IafterB - YoB;
  # 4) This return always 0, which confirm that column "IafterB" is ignored. Why?
  age_calculated <- IafterB;
  return (age_calculated);
}

# 3.4 Executes actual datasanity, replacing missing age with calculated one
# (should be rows from 13 to 19 included).
dataframe_csv$Age <- sub("-1", calculateAge(dataframe_csv$YoB, dataframe_csv$YoI, dataframe_csv$IafterB), dataframe_csv$Age);

# 3.4 Print result of the above datasanity
message("Whole dataframe after fixing missing Age:\n");
print(dataframe_csv);
message();

# 4. >>> PRODUCING OUTPUT FILE

# 4.1 Save current dataset object to in current working directory
write.csv2(dataframe_csv, dataset_file_out, row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE);
```

And this is the data test file:

```
Age;Sex;MoB;YoB;MoI;YoI
49;X ;8;1960;5;2010
49;*;8;1960;5;2010
67;1;1;1938;2;2006
;1;3;1940;8;2006
;1;4;1940;9;2006
;1;6;1940;10;2006
;1;8;1940;6;2006
;1;10;1940;2;2006
;1;11;1940;2;2006
;1;12;1940;2;2006
67;1;11;1940;2;2006
67;9;10;1938;2;2006
67;1;10;1938;2;9999
```

I tried many different formulas, but each one has a different issue. If I calculate age as follows:

```
age_calculated <- YoI - YoB;
```

I got a wrong value (e.g. 2006 - 1940 gives 68, instead of 66 !!!). If I calculate age as follows:

```
age_calculated <- YoI - YoB - 2;
```

I got the correct value, but I don't undertand why. If I calculate age as follows (this is the formula I'd like to use):

```
age_calculated <- YoI + IafterB - YoB;
```

The column "IafterB" is ignored. To confirm that such colum is ignored I tried also (wrong formula, used just to check if the column "IafterB" is considered or not):

```
age_calculated <- IafterB;
```

this set all missing Age values to "0", which proves that "-1" values on the column "IafterB" are ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the documentation, the `replacement` in `sub` can only be a single string, not a vector of replacements.  There are other ways to do what you want, eg with `ifelse`

Answer (score 2):

Use `coalesce`:

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(Age2 = coalesce(Age, YoI - YoB))
#    Age Sex MoB  YoB MoI  YoI Age2
# 1   49  X    8 1960   5 2010   49
# 2   49   *   8 1960   5 2010   49
# 3   67   1   1 1938   2 2006   67
# 4   NA   1   3 1940   8 2006   66
# 5   NA   1   4 1940   9 2006   66
# 6   NA   1   6 1940  10 2006   66
# 7   NA   1   8 1940   6 2006   66
# 8   NA   1  10 1940   2 2006   66
# 9   NA   1  11 1940   2 2006   66
# 10  NA   1  12 1940   2 2006   66
# 11  67   1  11 1940   2 2006   67
# 12  67   9  10 1938   2 2006   67
# 13  67   1  10 1938   2 9999   67
```

(I put it into a separate `Age2` solely for demonstration to have the two variables side-by-side, it is valid and likely easier to just use `Age=coalesce(...)`.)

These two statements are effectively equivalent, useful for understand what `coalesce` is doing:

```r
coalesce(Age, YoI - YoB)
if_else(is.na(Age), YoI - YoB, Age)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works wonderfully. May I ask why my original approach returned a substraction with an error of 2 units? It's non important, but I love to learn.

Comment: I don't know, frankly. The description of the problem seemed simple enough that I didn't try to parse through the 69 lines of code/comments to find what you were doing. Sorry, I know it is often useful to know where you went wrong.